# Number format with str_replace

Tags: php

I need to format my currency values to remove dots and comma and increase 00 in non cents values, this is the best way?

```
str_replace(['.',','],'', number_format('67.50',2)); return 6750 
str_replace(['.',','],'', number_format('112.35',2)); return 11235 
str_replace(['.',','],'', number_format('1001',2)); return 100100
```

Comment: I don't get your question. Why does 1001 equals to 100100?

Comment: @Wimanicesir It would be 1001.00, so formatted with 2 decimals.

Comment: Since you have the values already available, most likely as a `double` value anyway, why not just use `$var*100;`? Why the detour via `number_format()` and `str_replace`?

Comment: Read about [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). There is no need to `str_replace()` anything.

Comment: @axiac Thanks! I have skipt this in documentation, but I have used number_format($number, 2, '', '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BCMath extension of PHP directly.

Source code:

```
<?php
$num = bcmul('123.45', 100);
var_dump($num);

$num = bcmul('123.456', 100);
var_dump($num);

// The thrid parameter is used to set the number of digits after the decimal place in the result.
$num = bcmul('123.456', 100, 1);
var_dump($num);

$num = bcmul('123456.78', 100);
var_dump($num);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "12345"
string(5) "12345"
string(7) "12345.6"
string(8) "12345678"
```

For more information, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php